# Lost coin during hard drive upgrade

Tags: hd-wallets

I purchase one ether coin and sent it to my wallet stored on my apple computer.  I bought a new computer and had them clone my hard drive and bring everything over to my new mac.

My wallet is on the new computer, but the coin doesn't show up in my wallet.

How do I retrieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can check on https://etherscan.io/ if you still own those ethers by entering your public key.

If you can see your coins in your wallet, and you own a private key then you can use the following method to access your coins,

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#creating-an-account-by-importing-a-private-key

Comment: Thank you. It shows my 1 Ether still there.  Is private key where my coins were stored on my personal wallet on my computer?

Comment: private key holds your coins, there is nothing in your computer. You can import your private key using any computer or device and your coins will show up. As long as your private key is secure no one can steal your coins.